# Graph of curve showing distribution of numbers using Python

Tags: python, graph, curve

How could I draw a graph showing the distribution of a group of numbers using curved filled by different colours in Python? An example graph is shown as follows. Could I do that with Matplotlib or other packages?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) and [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have seaborn then this can be done using the distplot or more specifically as using the kdeplot as shown below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a= np.random.normat(0.5,0.5,1000)

sns.distplot(a);
# or kdeplot
sns.kdeplot(a, shade=True);
```